# A Finite Summation Involving 2017

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis

On Brilliant.org Priyanshu Mishra posted the following question (after which he deleted it):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2017} \frac{n^2+2017}{n^{2017}+11}$$

I have been stuck on this question for a while.  Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: **Hint:** It is not pretty as a fraction, but the numerical result is $$168.167$$ Using a single term, $n = 1$, gets you the result, so an argument that shows why that is the case is in order. Clear?

Comment: Got it, thanks!